# Calculate nth power of matrix $A$

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix $A$, and need to calculate its $n$th power for a problem.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
d & c
\end{bmatrix}$$
Please help me.

Comment: Diagonalize the matrix, write down the nth power in the eigenbasis and then transform back to the original basis by using the eigenvectors to construct the transformation matrix from the eigenbasis to the original basis.

Comment: If we can do this $A=VDV^{-1}$ then $A^n = VD^nV^{-1}$ where $D^n$ is just taking the diagonal elements to the power $n$.

Comment: @CountIblis: What if the matrix cannot be diagonalized?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: @RoryDaulton The set of diagonalizable matrices is dense in the set of all matrices, so if it isn't diagonalizable, it would still be the limit of a sequence of matrices with each matrix in the sequence being diagonalizable. The map defined by taking the nth power is a continuous map, so the limit will yield the correct result.

Answer (score 6):

cayley hamilton theorem tells you that $$A^2 -(a+c)A +(ac-bd)I = 0.\tag 1$$ that is you can replace $A^2$ by $(a+c)A -(ac-bd)I.$  in fact any power of $A$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $A$ and $I$ by using $(1)$ repeatedly. this amounts to using the division algorithm.

here is how it works. if you want to find $A^{100},$ write $$x^{100} = q(x)[x^2 - (a+c)x + (ac-bd)] + ex + f \tag 2$$
determine $e, f$ by plugging in the roots(eigenvalues) of $A.$ then $$A^{100} = eA + fI.$$